How many unique patterns can be made by placing $k$ counters on an $n\times m$ chess board?
How many unique patterns can be made by placing $k$ counters on an $n\times m$ chess board? Obviously we take $k\leq n\times m$.
Rotations and reflections should all be counted as distinct patternns (unless they are rotationally or reflectively symmetrical of course).
For instance, if $n=m=2$, and $k=3$, then the answer is $4$ (one for each possible spot of the empty square).
I can think that $\frac{(n\times m)!}{((n\times m)-k)!}$ is an upper bound on the answer (i.e. there are $n\times m$ places to place the first counter, $n\times m-1$ to place the second etc), but many of these are the same pattern. In the $n=m=2$ and $k=3$ example, the formula would yield $24$, which is obviously too many.

The $k$ counters are identical?  Rotations and such don't matter?  Then it's just $\binom {nm}k$.  After all, you are just choosing $k$ spots out of $mn$.   If you want to identify rotate or reflected arrangements, of course it is different.

The structure of the rectangle seems irrelevant to the problem. You just want to know the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $mn$ objects. Can you take it from here?

@lulu The $k$ counters are identical and I don't want to identify rotations or reflections, i.e. each of the four rotations should be a distinct pattern for example. I'll update the question to reflect this.

@Haran the rectangular structure comes from a wider problem context that isn't needed here, I included the grid structure just in case it was pertinent.

If one isn't allowed to put more than one counter per square, then each pattern with $k$ counters corresponds to a subset of size $k$ of the set $ m\times n $, a set with $m \cdot n$ elements. There are $C_k^{m\cdot n} = `\frac{(m \cdot n) !}{k! \cdot(m \cdot n -k)!}$ possibilities.
eg in your example, m = n = 2 and k = 3 hence the solution you gave : $C^4_3 = 4$.

I believe we are counting unique patterns up to translation
